# Filtering critical/fatal exceptions for use with AddVectoredExceptionHandler

Tags: c++, visual-c++, exception, c++17, terminate

Im trying improve exception diagnostics (more like basic crash handling) for some cases where `SetUnhandledExceptionFilter` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680634(v=vs.85).aspx) doesn't seem to help in catching the fatal errors. The case are when shutting down and different atexit functions and singleton destructors, etc.  are runnning (cleaning up). Also the case where a destructor will terminate due to a mismatched noexcept declaration is of some concern.

Using `AddVectoredExceptionHandler` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679274(v=vs.85).aspx) indeed instead seems a good alternative, as it functions more like a debuggers 'first chance exceptions', however it also therefore get called in (way) too many cases (also normal exceptions, some signals, etc.).

1. Ideally there would be a some kind of way to tell if the exception
   would be handled or if terminate were to be called as a result.
2. The exception code is another way to filter - with the cpp
   genereated throw exception code, it is obvious that it should continue -
   I have a feeling that it will be too much of boilerplating or trial
   and error to getting the 'correct' (fatal) exception codes to filter.

Answer (score 3):

VEH handlers added by `AddVectoredExceptionHandler` will handle exceptions before they reach frame-based handlers.

Filter set by `SetUnhandledExceptionFilter` will handle exceptions after frame-based handlers failed.

Both normal processing (like `try...except` or `try...catch`) and signal handlers are implemented as frame-based handers, signal handers as the last frame-based handlers.

There's no reliable way to distinguish *fatal* and *non-fatal* exceptions until chain is unwound. Both language exception (code `0xE06D7363`), other software exceptions, and hardware exception (like access violation with code `0xC0000005`) -- all could be both fatal and non-fatal.

So, `AddVectoredExceptionHandler` is hardly of use. You'll have to handle `set_terminate`, `signal`, `_set_invalid_parameter_handler`, etc in addition to `SetUnhandledExceptionFilter`.

You may make sure that handlers of `signal` falls back to default by setting `SIG_DFL`, in this case it will fall-back to handler set by `SetUnhandledExceptionFilter`.

Default `_set_invalid_parameter_handler` intentionally does not fall back to handler set by `SetUnhandledExceptionFilter`, but if you set your function passed to `_set_invalid_parameter_handler` to raise your own SEH exception, it will fall back to handler set by `SetUnhandledExceptionFilter`.

I don't remember what's with `set_terminate` and others. You'll need to experiment with that. But as very last resort, you may always raise your own SEH exception, catch it with __except, and pass to `UnhandledExceptionFilter`, then your `SetUnhandledExceptionFilter` callback will be called:

```
__try
{
     RaiseException(0xE0000001,0,0,NULL);
}
__except(UnhandledExceptionFilter(GetExceptionInformation()))
{
}
```

Comment: You answer is really good, but lacking of a simpel solution though I am hoping for. set_terminate,etc.  would have been a good alternative - if only the interesting part of the stack wouldn't have already been unwound by the time the terminate handler is called. I have also found that exception is not enough alone - since you have STD that throws exceptions of the user type eg. `throw std::bad_alloc{}` . This can be thrown inside a destructor when the program is exiting.

Comment: Here is a solution which has an example how to register all other exception types, i.e., abort, etc: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/207464/Exception-Handling-in-Visual-Cplusplus

Answer (score 0):

Well, what you can do is add the vectorized exception handler but do not actually inspect the exception there, but either store it somewhere (a map mapping thread ids to some part of the exception info) and install your termination handler - if it is called, then you know that one of the exceptions in your map is the faulty one. To avoid keeping excess data, add a thread local raii class that removes the entries from the map, once threads exit. Of course this is kind of a performance hit (locking the map upon every exception), but if this really is what you want, then this is a valid approach.

General code:

```
#include <exception>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

#include <Windows.h>

void termination_handler()
{
    // Look at the map, you will not know which one caused it but at least have all of them
    std::cout << "termination_handler called\n";
}

LONG VectoredExceptionHandler(_EXCEPTION_POINTERS *ExceptionInfo)
{
    // Put exception record somewhere - e.g map of thread ids to to exception record, maybe symbols
    return EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_SEARCH;
}

void foo()  
{
    throw std::exception();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    AddVectoredExceptionHandler(0, VectoredExceptionHandler);
    std::set_terminate(termination_handler);
    std::thread t(foo);
    t.join();
    return 0;
}
```